# .NET not deserializing XSD maxOccurs="unbounded" element

Tags: .net, serialization, xsd, wsdl

In attempting to consume a WSDL that declares an array of types, .NET is unable to deserialize the response messge.

**WSDL**

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5Se_xHASR2LS0EtdmxfNGZWMTg

**Autogenerated Client proxy code**

Visual studio creates the following definition for this service operation response message.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse", WrapperNamespace="http://www.acme.com/webservices/connectors/731/servicerequest/message" +
    "types", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.acme.com/schema/uniform/731/servicerequest/sr/srtypes", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ServiceRequestSummary")]
    public ServiceRequestSummaryType[] ServiceRequestSummary;

    public GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse() {
    }

    public GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse(ServiceRequestSummaryType[] ServiceRequestSummary) {
        this.ServiceRequestSummary = ServiceRequestSummary;
    }
}
```

This does not work and the serializer cannot deserialise the ServiceRequestSummaryType objects in the ServiceRequestSummaryType[] so its always empty no matter if the responce ontains them.

**Response SOAP messge**

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></s:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse xmlns="http://www.acme.com/webservices/connectors/731/servicerequest/messagetypes">
            <ServiceRequestSummary xmlns="http://www.acme.com/schema/uniform/731/servicerequest/sr/srtypes">
                <ServiceRequestIdentification>
                    <ServiceRequestTechnicalKey>MD2P24BENM001</ServiceRequestTechnicalKey>
                    <ReferenceValue>12/00056/SR</ReferenceValue>
                    <AlternativeReferences>
                        <AlternativeReference xmlns="http://www.acme.com/schema/uniform/72b/common/uniformtypes">
                            <ReferenceValue>ssa</ReferenceValue>
                            <ReferenceType>FIRM</ReferenceType>
                        </AlternativeReference>
                    </AlternativeReferences>
                </ServiceRequestIdentification>
                <SiteLocation>
                    <Address>                       </Address>
                    <UPRN></UPRN>
                </SiteLocation>
                <NatureOfComplaint>Test</NatureOfComplaint>
                <AdministrationDetails>
                    <RequestTypeCode>DFOUL</RequestTypeCode>
                    <RequestTypeText>Dog fouling</RequestTypeText>
                    <RequestKindCode>D</RequestKindCode>
                    <RequestKindText>Dog Request</RequestKindText>
                    <AllocatedToCode>EHCALL</AllocatedToCode>
                    <AllocatedToText></AllocatedToText>
                    <TimeAllocated></TimeAllocated>
                    <AllocationHistory>
                        <AllocationHistoryDetail>
                            <OfficerCode>EHCALL</OfficerCode>
                            <OfficerName>EH Call Centre</OfficerName>
                            <AllocationDateTime>2012</AllocationDateTime>
                        </AllocationHistoryDetail>
                    </AllocationHistory>
                    <HowReceivedCode>TELE</HowReceivedCode>
                    <HowReceivedText>telephone</HowReceivedText>
                    <TimeReceived>2012-11-02T13:40:00</TimeReceived>
                    <StatusCode>1_NEW</StatusCode>
                    <StatusText>1_NEW - New Request</StatusText>
                </AdministrationDetails>
                <SubjectDetails>
                    <SubjectContactDetails></SubjectContactDetails>
                </SubjectDetails>
                <RequestType>DOG</RequestType>
                <RequestKindCode>D</RequestKindCode>
                <RequestKindText>Dog Request</RequestKindText>
            </ServiceRequestSummary>
        </GetServiceRequestSummariesMatchingProfileResponse>
        <TransactionReport xmlns="">
            <TransactionComplete>True</TransactionComplete>
            <TransactionSuccess>True</TransactionSuccess>
            <TransactionMessages></TransactionMessages>
        </TransactionReport>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However after hunting around the net, I noticed somthing similar with no explanation however. If I change the auto generated code to include the namespace ;

so insted of

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ServiceRequestSummary")]
```

we have

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ServiceRequestSummary", Namespace = "http://www.acme.com/schema/uniform/731/servicerequest/sr/srtypes")]
```

It then will work. I don’t understand what is wrong with the WSDL or the response message that is making the deserialization fail, after all VS has auto generated its client proxy code from the WSDL without any errors.

Changing the auto-gen code is not a workable solution, if you can spot what’s might be causing this have a cigar.

Comment: I can't connect to that URL.

Comment: Apologies, modified the link to the correct google docs shared link. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5Se_xHASR2LS0EtdmxfNGZWMTg

Answer (score 0):

According to XMLSpy, this WSDL is not valid:

```
File C:\Temp\Untitled1.wsdl is not valid.
    Invalid XML schema: ''s4:ServiceRequestIdentificationType' must refer to an existing simple or complex type.'
        Error location: wsdl:definitions / wsdl:types / s:schema / s:complexType / s:sequence / s:element / @type
```

How did you generate the proxy? SVCUTIL? If so, then you need to supply the path of *all* XML Schema files on the command line.

Comment: The WSDL has been updated. I have now included the full original WSDL via a link as this site considered it too large to include within the thread.

Comment: The proxy was generated using visual studio 'add reference'.  The WSDL does not appear to have any imports, it looks to be all inline.